# File Authentication: Need to prompt authentication when opening a file on every time

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have to prompt an authentication for a file while opening on every time. I have tried it with PHP Authentication.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
}
```

But, It is not asking for every time. 
Can we do it either using Htaccess or Htpasswd?

Please advice.

Comment: If it is not asking every time it would imply that one of the conditions is being met, try changing it from `||` to `&&`

Comment: `||` means OR. Try `&&` which means AND.

Comment: @YUNOWORK & Pwner: It should be authenticated every time.

Comment: That’s not how HTTP Auth works – your browser remembers the credentials and automatically sends them with every following request. (Otherwise, on a page with resources like scripts, stylesheets, images etc. embedded that are also within the same realm, you would be prompted again for each and every one of those, and that can obviously not be the desired effect for the normal use case.)

Comment: Although you can kinda “clear” the browsers memory [by answering a request with a 401 Unauthorized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#example-353), for your case you would have to find a way of checking whether or not the client requested that resource before, so that you know _when_ to send that header – I’m not sure if there’s a trivial solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using .htaccess & .htpasswd

create file .htaccess & put :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/.htpasswd  # should be you file path & .htpasswd
require valid-user
```

the above solution for whole directory. if you want for single file than use this in .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "demo.php" # name of the file for which you want authentication
AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/.htpasswd #path of the folder
<Files "demo.php">

  require valid-user

</Files>
```

in .htpasswd

```
test:do43GnYbHanDE #username test & pwd (download)
```

You can create your .htpasswd password from [here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it in my local wamp. I'm getting Internal Server Error. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your document root path . use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: I have placed the htaccess file in a directory "auth". I have created an index.html in there only(in auth).

Comment: have you put the .htpasswd in same directory ?

Comment: that is wrong put the .htaccess & .htpasswd in this auth directory and make sure dont copy your parent .htaccess in auth.create the new one here

Comment: i have given the example of lampp. i think you are using wampp so please find the document root path first of that file and then try.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Harshal. I will check in another server.

Comment: you don't need to change the whole server. just change the path in my code